# Get a free LIVE CD. (ShipIt)

Tags: cd

I do not find the ShipIt on the site. You can pass me the link? (Ubuntu CD with free shipping) It arrives in Brazil? Thanks.

Comment: ShipIt service is not available since Ubuntu 10.04 (I think that is the last ShipIt I got). So you can burn the dvd by your self. Refer this link for the reason why >> http://askubuntu.com/questions/131139/why-did-ubuntu-stop-free-shipping-of-its-cds.

Answer (score 3):

ShipIt service has now closed.

The old link was: http://www.ubuntu.com/shipit

Accessing the link will redirect you to the URL (link) provided below

For more details regarding ShipIt's closing, please read the link:
http://blog.canonical.com/2011/04/05/shipit-comes-to-an-end/